# Can I add a default script line to package.json

Tags: node.js, json, frontend

I'm a beginner in the field of frontend development and I'm starting to work on building small projects and assignments.

I was wondering how I could add a default script line to every package.json file I create using the npm init command. (I'm on MacOS)

I found out how to set the default author name (which created the .npmrc file in my home directory), however I can't seem to figure out to add the following as a default to all package files:

`"scripts": { "start": "live-server --browser=firefox" },`

It seems trivial, but as we'll be building out our set-up, there will be certain scripts defaults we'll need in every projects, such as "deploy" settings etc.

Is there an easy way to add this as a default so that this is pre-added with every npm init command?

Or: a classmate of mine created an automator workflow to set-up a new project folder including some starting files and a command that already runs the npm init on that folder. Is there a terminal command to add the above line to the scripts section of the package.json file which we could add to the automator workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom scripts using the following command in the CLI:

```
npm set-script dev "nodemon server.js"
```

Result in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  }
```

Consult the documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-set-script).

You can also write it in a shell script file to automate your projects.